# drush coder-review in specified folder

Tags: drush

How can i perform code review with coder_review command in a specified folder?
I see that i can give it contrib or core directives, but i would like to only check a folder in my modules folder like

/modules/dev

/modules/contrib/

/modules/custom/

How should i instruct coder-review command to check those modules (custom) only?

Tried `drush coder-review <folder-path>` that doesnt seem to work, is there any other option, or should i patch the module to accept my 'custom' directive?

Answer (score 1):

This was solved with a patch to coder module(7.x-1.2), introducing my custom command argument, "custom" which selects the modules i want form the database using a machine name query.

Coder review will never work on a file-system basis, since it grabs the module info from the database not the file-system.